# Is it Possible to Add ActionListener in the JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jformattedtextfield

Hello I'm currently working in my java file.
I'd like to add an event on JFormattedTextField when I press the enter key.
This is my code

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.text.ParseException;

    public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
        JFormattedTextField phoneField;
        Test()
        {
            setTitle("JFormatted Text");
    setLayout(null);
    MaskFormatter mask = null;
    try {
        mask = new MaskFormatter("##########");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    phoneField = new JFormattedTextField(mask);
    phoneField.setBounds(20, 20, 150, 30);
    phoneField.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(200, 200);
    getContentPane().add(phoneField);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()== phoneField)
        {
            System.out.println("The numbers you enter are "+phoneField.getText());
        }
    }
    }
```

it works but their the user needs to enter 10 digits.

Comment: what do you actually want to do in this code?What's the actual problem?

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, that's the exclusive task of a LayoutManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a keyListener instead.

```
phonefield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_ENTER){
        System.out.println("The numbers you enter are "+phoneField.getText());
    }
    }
});
```

If this isn't your problem, you should expand a little and clarify.

EDIT:
As comments and other answers pointed out, you should go for an `ActionListener` instead. Reasoning can be found below.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great help for me.

Comment: @user2081574 This is not a good idea, consider using the `ActionListener` as suggested in the other answer

Comment: @Reimeus: could you provide an explanation as to why an `ActionListener` is prefered over a `KeyListener`?

Comment: `KeyListener` is meant for the use with older `AWT` components and do not provide consistent behavior with Swing components accross all platforms. For `JTextComponents`, use `DocumentListener` for document changes or `ActionListener` for simple `ActionEvents`.

Answer (score 3):

Add an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to the field.  It is better than using the (low level) `KeyListener` and will conform to whatever that OS accepts as 'end of entry'.

Comment: @Brent please again to read this answer, never to use KeyListener for JTextComponents,

Comment: +1, the addActionListener() method was added to to JTextField for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `KeyListener` instead use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html).

It has the following methods which captures the changes in the `JTextField`

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                // Gives notification that a portion of the document has been removed.

            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                // Gives notification that there was an insert into the document.

            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            // Gives notification that an attribute or set of attributes changed.

            }
        });
```